# Istio-init container has gone to crash loopbackoff

Tags: kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks

I am istio-init(version 1.6.5) as a sidecar container in my k8s cluster, it been working fine for a while. Today, out of blue my pod has gone to Init:CrashloopbackOff

```
NAME                                 READY       STATUS                     RESTARTS       AGE 
healthscore-green-79c9c5c764-cndm6    0/2       Init:CrashLoopBackOff          388        2d17h
```

on kubectl describe it shows:

```
istio-init: 
  Container ID: docker://657be7ddd9058406da7768596c81490b426a376816b8b4f20fbb63c0c44b5a13 
  Image: docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.6.5 
  Image ID: docker-pullable://istio/proxyv2@sha256:ec2df06d76e8845fbce0ac1b4b85ab06a7beabab8a69fcc3bb2b573378b71c47
  Port: Host 
  Port: Args: istio-iptables -p 15001 -z 15006 -u 1337 -m REDIRECT -i * -x -b * -d 15090,15021,15020      
  State: Waiting 
  Reason: CrashLoopBackOff 
  Last State: Terminated Reason: 
  Error Exit Code: 2 
  Started: Mon, 28 Sep 2020 14:21:23 +0530 
  Finished: Mon, 28 Sep 2020 14:21:23 +0530
  Ready: False 
  Restart Count: 392 
  Limits:
    cpu: 100m 
    memory: 50Mi
  Requests: 
     cpu: 10m
     memory: 10Mi
```

and kubectl logs of the istio-container prints the following stack trace:
https://pastebin.com/GAuNndd5

Also one thing I noticed, since `istio-init` side car is failing according to kubernetes, but my application is able to serve http requests.
It get fixed automatically after some time.
but reoccurs once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

From the logs it's failing to `executeIptablesRestoreCommand`. The kubernetes nodes might have gone through some reboot or upgrade .Disable the SELinux temporarily by doing `sudo setenforce 0` on the kubernetes node and then re-run your `istioctl kube-inject`

Comment: thanks for the reply.
i will try your suggestion. 
but what is the correct way to resolve this in production environment

Comment: What is your istio verson?

Comment: latest version
service.istio.io/canonical-revision: latest

Comment: as i checked SELinux is disable in all nodes.